# epsilon and delta multivariate proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Prove $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0)}(1-xy)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \text{e}^{y_0}$$

I know how to compute it by taking the **log** but I'm a bit stumped as to how i would prove it using epsilon delta.

Comment: $\log$ is continuous on its domain, so can't you just appeal to some theorem about composition with continuous functions, without using epsilon-delta?